# dotnet ValidateDataAnnotations specify message

Tags: c#, validation, config

I want to validate configuration. My IOptions class:

```
public class ConnectionOptions
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field {0} is required")]
    public string Connection { get; set; }
}
```

And then in Startup.cs I set up configuration and validation:

```
services.AddOptions<ConnectionOptions>()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

When I try to get value of `IOptions<ConnectionOptions>` instance, in case when `Connection` setting was not specified, I get `OptionsValidationException` with one string in `Failures` property:

> DataAnnotation validation failed for members: 'Connection' with the error: 'Field Connection is required'.

But I want shorter, simpler message. Text `Field Connection is required` would be better.

Can I specify any settings to get this shorter message? If I can't do it with settings, I am going to just cut it of with regexes.

Comment: I also can implement `IValidateOptions<ConnectionOptions>` and send custom validation messages, but I think it is too much boilercode

Comment: You can't change the message. [The source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations/src/DataAnnotationValidateOptions.cs) shows it's hard-coded. You could create your own validation method and classes instead. [The full source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations/src) is just a class file that implements `IValidateOptions` and the extension method `ValidateDataAnnotations` that registers it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks, you can repost this comment as answer, because it is an answer to my question